# MYSQL return 0 for filtered rows

Tags: mysql, sum

I am trying to filter with a "WHERE" but I want to display the filtered rows as "NULL" or 0 instead of hiding them.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT *, IFNULL(SUM(ROUND(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,start,end)/60,1)),0) urlaub 
FROM time_entries e
LEFT JOIN users u ON e.user_id = u.id
WHERE e.project_id = 10 AND YEAR(end) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
GROUP BY e.user_id
```

Best,
Chris

Comment: Remove the  WHERE and move it in your select CASE WHEN e.project_id = 10 AND YEAR(end) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE THEN .. but you`ll have to do it for each column

Comment: @Mihai Out of curiosity, any reason your first instinct was a `CASE WHEN` instead of just an `IF()`?

Comment: Thanks Mihai, that did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

I might be just being pedantic, but in case there is a genuine misunderstanding.... They are not "hidden", they are not there. The point of the WHERE is to choose which records to retrieve, so as to not retrieve the entire table contents when only a few records of data are relevant.

But if something like that is what you want to do, you should just be able to add another result field, like so:
`(e.project_id = 10 AND YEAR(end) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)) AS relevantRecord`

Answer (score 0):

Got it working! This is the code that returns what I wanted to:

```
SELECT
*,
IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN e.project_id = 10 AND YEAR(end) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) THEN ROUND(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, start, end)/60,1) ELSE 0 END),0) AS urlaub
FROM time_entries e
LEFT JOIN users u ON e.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY e.user_id
```

Thanks!